# Parcel / ES6: Bootstrap function not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ecmascript-6, node-modules, parcel

I'm new to ES6 / Node Modules / Parcel but so far everything worked fine, but as I can see the Bootstrap functions aren't working.

Here's the part of the code that throws errors:

```js
import 'typeface-montserrat'
import jquery from "jquery";
export default (window.$ = window.jQuery = jquery);
import 'bootstrap';
import './css/main.scss';

if($('#news-carousel .carousel-item').length < 5)
{
    //this function is not working
    $('#news-carousel').carousel({
        interval: false
    });
}

//tested this too and it wont working either
$("#modalId").modal("show");
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).carousel is not a function
```

Comment: Are there any error you can show us? (e.g. in your browser console)

Comment: sorry, you are right. I just edited the question

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figure it out how to handle this.

After many failed tests, this worked:

```js
import 'typeface-montserrat'
import jquery from "jquery";
export default (window.$ = window.jQuery = jquery);
import 'bootstrap';
import './css/main.scss';

//import the proper classes from bootstrap
import { Carousel, Modal } from 'bootstrap';

//handle the Carousel configuration, in this I wanted to stop the slides
new Carousel($('#news-carousel')[0], {
    interval: false
});

//initialize the Modal class
var modal = new Modal($('#modalId')[0]);
//show the modal
modal.show();
//hide the modal
modal.hide();
```